# Word counter: Doesn't seem to give the output I need (PHP)

Tags: php

here's the line of code that I came up with:

```
function Count($text)
        {    
            $WordCount = str_word_count($text);         

            $TextToArray = explode(" ", $text);
            $TextToArray2 = explode(" ", $text);

            for($i=0; $i<$WordCount; $i++)
            {
                $count = substr_count($TextToArray2[$i], $text);
            }
            echo "Number of {$TextToArray2[$i]} is {$count}";                                                   
        }
```

So, what's gonna happen here is that, the user will be entering a text, sentence or paragraph. By using substr_count, I would like to know the number of occurrences of the word inside the array. Unfortunately, the output the is not what I really need. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're trying to figure out how many times each word appears in a sentence or paragraph or text?

Comment: str_word_count($text) can also be used to count word frequences... where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want an array with the word frequencies.

First off, convert the string to lowercase and remove all punctuation from the text. This way you won't get entries for "But", "but", and "but," but rather just "but" with 3 or more uses.

Second, use `str_word_count` with a second argument of 2 as Mark Baker says to get a list of words in the text. This will probably be more efficient than my suggestion of preg_split.

Then walk the array and increment the value of the word by one.

```
foreach($words as $word)
  $output[$word] = isset($output[$word]) ? $output[$word] + 1 : 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Robert K, could you explain further? Sorry but I am having a hard time understanding your instructions. I am still a newbie and inexperienced please understand.

Comment: I finally got it to work. Thanks a lot @Robert K. really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

If I had understood your question correctly this should also solve your problem

```
function Count($text) {
   $TextToArray = explode(" ", $text); // get all space separated words
   foreach($TextToArray as $needle) {
     $count = substr_count($text, $needle); // Get count of a word in the whole text
     echo "$needle has occured  $count times in the text";
   }
}
```

Comment: while this works, you will count the number of times each word is used each time it is encountered.

Comment: @RobertK ya you are correct. I just wanted the poster to know that he doesn't need to do a `str_word_count` instead he can go with a `foreach` on exploded array :) This is obviously not a optimal soln :) I posted this answer after seeing your soln. That is why I had mentioned this should also solve his problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$WordCounts = array_count_values(str_word_count(strtolower($text),2));
var_dump($WordCounts);
```

Comment: This doesn't actually count the number of times a word is used. He'll still need to use the loop I created to actually do a frequency count.