# Interview - how calculate the frequency of each word in a text file

Tags: php

I had an interview where I could use any language I wanted to in order to calculate how many times each word appeared in a text file.

I solved it in C by reading in each word and adding it to a tree structure - If the word was all ready in the structure, the algorithm would add one to a counter I added in the node.

Well the person said I had to much code and it was messy, and said I could do it in PHP with about 3 lines of code.

I started to use the `explode()` to separate the string into a array of words, but was stuck after that.

Does anybody know how this could be done in PHP with a couple lines of code?

Comment: `I had a intervene ware I could use any lagug` I hope you didn't try to use English

Comment: Just for future reference, many browsers have built-in spell checkers, and it is highly encouraged you use them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word counter: Doesn't seem to give the output I need (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651271/word-counter-doesnt-seem-to-give-the-output-i-need-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to read the complete file in as a string with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents), split it up on whitespace, and run the resulting array through [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array_count_values)

```
$file = file_get_contents( 'text_file.txt');
$array = preg_split( '/\s+/', $file); 
$counts = array_count_values( $array);
```

Done!

However, this isn't perfect, as punctuation can mess up your count. So, as Mark Baker points out, we can go back to my original method of getting all of the words in the file with [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/str_word_count), then running that array through `array_count_values()`:

```
$file = file_get_contents( 'text_file.txt');
$words = str_word_count( $file, 1);
$counts = array_count_values( $words);
```

Comment: I did, I will update my answer in a bit. (TBH had no clue was frency was)

Comment: array_count_values() should finish the job.... though you might also add strtolower()